# What is the correct method for publishing and pulling an Android Studio Gradle project to and from GitHub?

Tags: java, android, github, gradle

I understand the menu items to click etc but my paths for dependencies are different on one PC to another which causes no end of problems.

Is there a 'cheat sheet' of settings I need to change after importing to get the project working on the second computer?

Or can it be clever enough to look in the right places somehow?

Comment: Do you mean project dependencies? Like your project depends on another library project?

Comment: Yes, to give an example, every time I do a pull onto my second computer I lose the navigation drawer stuff (that Android Studio auto adds to your project) plus the support libraries etc. 

Also I couldn't even extend a BaseAdapter last night from a raw pull request which should be standard stuff?

Comment: Could you share your gradle file?

Comment: I'm under NDA so unfortunately I can't. But this has been an issue with all of the tests I have run on Android Studio in the past.

Comment: Tomorrow at work I will create another project and share that - will do some screenshots too. But I am certain it's because of things being installed in different places on each machine...

Comment: Or did you mean the build.gradle file?

Comment: Looks like deleting the .idea folder and the .iml files solved it - will have to exclude them from my commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like deleting the .idea folder and the .iml files solved it - will have to exclude them from my commits.